# Debugging- stepping in to OS functions?

Tags: c++, c, linux, unix, eclipse-cdt

When coding C++ on Linux I use Eclipse CDT. When stepping into a C/C++ OS function I can see the assembler, but considering the files are all stored in /usr/include/ I thought the debugger would then step into each line of C/C++.

So, is there any way to debug C++ on Linux which does allow you to step in to the C/C++ of the OS functions?

Comment: You can't run a debugger against code that's running in the kernel, because it could create a deadlock in the kernel if the debugger hits a breakpoint at an inconvenient time. There is a kernel debugger on many systems, but it can't usually link to userland code as well, and sometimes must be accessed via the serial port from another machine. If you're interested in live kernel debugging on the system being debugged, check out [DTrace](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DTrace) on Mac OS X, a BSD, or Solaris.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can do it with gdb (GNU debugger) under Linux. The interface is quite rude, but it does the job. A little example : first, launch gdb.

```
gdb your_program
```

Then, you are in it.

```
....
Reading symbols from foobar...done.
(gdb) start # begin the debug session
...
(gdb) disas # show the disassembly code of the current function (main)
.... # lot of asm
0x00000000004007d4 <+17>:    call   0x400440 <malloc@plt>
0x00000000004007d9 <+22>:    mov    QWORD PTR [rax],0x0
0x00000000004007e0 <+29>:    push   rax
... # lot of asm
(gdb) break *0x4007d4 # set a break point at the address of the call malloc
Breakpoint 2 at 0x4007d4
(gdb) run # run until breakpoint
...
Breakpoint 2, 0x00000000004007d4 in main () # the breakpoint has been reached
=> 0x00000000004007d4 <main+17>:        e8 67 fc ff ff  call   0x400440 <malloc@plt>
(gdb) si # step into the malloc
0x0000000000400440 in malloc@plt ()
=> 0x0000000000400440 <malloc@plt+0>:   ff 25 92 11 20 00       jmp    QWORD PTR [rip+0x201192]        # 0x6015d8 <malloc@got.plt> # you see code from malloc now
(gdb) ni # next instruction in malloc
...
(gdb) finish # quit the current function, actually malloc
(gdb)
```

However, you won't be able to easily display the high-level corresponding source code. The best you can do is simultaneously read the libraries/kernel code.

For example, you can read the code of of malloc from glibc (the GNU standard C library) [here](http://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/glibc/glibc-2.17.tar.bz2), in `malloc/malloc.c`.